# Can't deploy GIT php/python3 project <-> AWS on heroku

Tags: python-3.x, git, heroku, amazon-s3, deployment

When i want to deploy a student project (php/python) from git to heroku, 
Some python scripts read data from aws server via mysql.connect

When i try to deploy log say:

---

```
   App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz

   More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

   !     Push failed
```

---

That the first time i use heroku, totaly lost

If somenone can help
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use the Python buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python

Your app is not recognized as a Python project on Heroku if none of the following files are present:

- `requirements.txt`
- `setup.py`
- `Pipfile`

see here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/detect

Usually people provide a `requirements.txt`. You probably also want to provide a Python version. You do it via `runtime.txt`. Try to match the Python version on development and production.

You can create a `requirements.txt` with `python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`.